How to force a DOM refresh in a background tab for a Chrome extension?
I'm developing a Chrome extension that needs to parse DOM data from a background tab. However, I've noticed that the DOM data isn't always up-to-date unless the user actively switches to that tab. I believe this behavior is part of Chrome's optimization to save memory and improve performance. Is there any method or workaround that would allow me to force a refresh of the DOM in a background tab without requiring the user to switch to it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

refresh on a regular time interval? Does this help?

@Raptor thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately refreshing the tab is not possible as the DOM data is not saved after reload.

It means the site is intentionally pausing its work when its tab is not active. You'll have to spoof the method used by the site to detect it's not active. Either use devtools debugger to find the specific method or spoof them all. The spoofing code will need to be in a content script in the MAIN world. See also timer throttling for backgrounded tabs.
